# What is the structure of the Presentation-Data-Value in P-Data-TF?

Tags: dicom

I find these for Presentation Data Value:

```
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | last-or-not | command-or-dataset | **Some Message**
```

But I couldn't find **Some Message** part. I suppose this part include C-Find, C-Get etc. How can I know this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you have this from? In fact it is a bit different.

Your example should read

```
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | last-or-not | command-or-data*set* | **Some Message**
```

So the "command-or-dataset" flag indicates whether the following bytes are encoding a **command** (as defined in PS3.7) or a **dataset** as defined in PS3.3 or 3.4 respectively).

E.g. for DICOM Queries, there is a **C-FIND** command defined in PS3.7, Chapter 9.1.2.1. In C-FIND, the query criteria are part of the command ("Identifier") in table 9.1-2. How the identifier is formed and all its semantics is subject of the **Query/Retrieve Service Class** as defined in PS3.4, C.4.1.

For transferring objects, there is a **C-STORE** command, also defined in PS3.7 (chapter 9.1.1.1). The Data-Set is also a part of the C-STORE command, and its contents depend on the **type of data** (SOP Class). This is referred to as an **Information Object Definition (IOD)** and defined in PS3.3. The protocol for Strorage is also defined in PS3.4 (Annex B)
However, the length limitation of the PDV will only allow to have the whole object encoded in a single PDV and **needs to be split**. For the following PDVs, no command set will be present but only a **fragment of the dataset**. In this case, the "command-or-dataset" bit must be set to 0.

I hope I could make it a bit clear. It is a bit difficult in the beginning of learning DICOM to know all the terms and the interrelationships.

**Encoding**

Logically command- and dataset are encoded in the same way. The data dictionary (Part 6) is a complete list of all possible attributes and the major difference between command- and data set attributes is that command attributes are having the group number 0 while data set attributes have "any even number but 0".

For each attribute, the data dictionary gives you the Value Representation (VR) which needs to be considered for encoding the value. E.g. "PN" for patient name "UI" for Unique Identifier and so forth. The VRs are defined in PS3.5, Chapter 6.2.
The encoding of attributes is then

```
group | element | (VR) | length (always even) | value
```

How this is transformed to the binary level depends on the Transfer Syntax (TS) that was agreed for the service during association negotiation. For this reason "VR" is enclosed in brackets above - it depends whether it is an implicit or explicit TS if this must/must not be present.

There are some more things to consider (endianess, sequence encoding) when encoding code sets or datasets in binary form. Basically everything about it is described in various chapters in PS3.5

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited 'dataset'. Actually I want to know how can I encode them (to bytes). For example C-FIND has Message ID, SOP Class UID, Priority etc. I couldn't find how to encode these part. I'm looking for something similar to these figures: (For example: PS3.8, 9.3.1 figures)

Comment: A DIMSE Message's Command Set is always encoded *Little Endian Implicit VR*, The Message's (optional-ish) Data Set is encoded using the Transfer Syntax from the matching agreed upon Presentation Context. See [Part 5 of the DICOM Standard](https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/chapter_7.html#sect_7.1) for dataset encoding details.

Comment: To be a bit clearer, the Command Set and Data Set are both treated as a typical DICOM *dataset*, the only difference is the Command Set has elements matching the particular request/response type (i.e. *Message ID*, *Affected SOP Class*, *Priority*, etc), while the Data Set is the information being exchanged (i.e. the Identifier query/responses in the case of C-FIND). Both are encoded following the rules in Part 5, and both get encapsulated within P-DATA-TF PDVs.

Comment: @great-sky: I added a few more hints on encoding to my post. But everything beyond that would turn this post into a comprehensive DICOM tutorial rather than into an answer to a question.